# Получить уникальные элементы списка, сохранив порядок

Tags: python, python-3.x, список

Подскажите, как можно перезапустить внешний цикл при условии находящимся внутри вложенного цикла:

```
n = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
for i in range(0, len(n)):
    for p in range((i + 1), len(n)):
        if n[i] == n[p]:
            n.pop(i)
            n.pop(p)
            # здесь нужно перезапустить цикл(for i in range(0, len(n))...)
```

Цикл будет повторятся пока из списка не будут удалены все повторяющиеся эллементы. Потом я просто выведу оставшиеся.

Comment: А какую функцию нужно перезапустить?

Comment: И второй вопрос, не долго ли будет работать твой цикл? Так как, у меня складывается ощущение будто цикл будет идти бесконечно)

Comment: Цикл будет идти до тех пор, пока из списка не будут удалены все повторяющиеся элементы. Потом я хочу вывести все оставшиеся элементы.

Comment: А что тебе мешает написать `n = set([int(i) for i in input().split()])`

Comment: перезапуск цикла какого либо блока кода? здесь нужна рекурсия... но у вас очень простая задача `t = []; for i in n:; if i not in t:;  t.append(i)`

Comment: нет, ваша программа просто убирает 2ые, 3ии повторяющиеся элементы. А в задаче нужно вывести все элементы которые в списке встречаются только один раз

Comment: `a=[1,2,"x",3,1,"y",2,"x",5] ; [elem for count,elem in enumerate(a) if a.count(elem)==1]` так что ли?

Comment: И вообще Вы как-то не очень корректно задали вопрос. Надо было так "Необходимо вывести все элементы в списке встречающиеся только один раз. Для этого я написал такой-то код но столкнулся с такой-то проблемой. Подскажите как её исправить или помогите найти другое решение задачи."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Вот несколько вариантов получить список уникальных элементов списка (сложность алгоритма `O(n)`), сохраняя порядок элементов](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17016257/5741205):

```
>>> from  more_itertools import unique_everseen
>>> items = [1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 2]
>>> list(unique_everseen(items))
[1, 2, 0, 3]
```

---

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> items = [1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 2]
>>> list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(items))
[1, 2, 0, 3]
```

---

```
seen = set()
[x for x in items if x not in seen and not seen.add(x)]
```

PS если порядок элементов сохранять не обязательно, то самый простой и быстрый способ:

```
res = list(set(items))
```